Google Scripts, script disabled
I am new to writing some scripts. I have this function right here, that i created. It always comes with an interval of 2 hours. Everytime, that the trigger was used, it gets disabled. I have to delete them and start them again. Is there a way to re-enable the scripts, or to delete and recreate them daily?
They always have to come at the certain time.
I used the script below:
function setTriggerNL() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(7); //Allows to set a preferable time to start
  startTime.setMinutes(45);
  startTime.setSeconds(0);

  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(23); //Allows to set a preferable time to end
  endTime.setMinutes(45);
  endTime.setSeconds(0);

  var intervalMinutes = 120; //Works with a 120 Minutes interval 

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var nextRunTime = new Date();
  nextRunTime.setTime(Math.ceil(currentTime.getTime() / (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000)) * (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));

  if (nextRunTime < startTime) {
    nextRunTime = startTime;
  }

  while (nextRunTime <= endTime) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('NewsletterHTML')
      .timeBased()
      .at(nextRunTime)
      .create();

    nextRunTime.setTime(nextRunTime.getTime() + (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));
  }
}


Maybe you have too many triggers, so you'll need to handle how to first delete and then recreate the triggers daily.

The multiple trigger is not the issue. It just gets disabled after it was used once. My issue is here, that i do want to recreate them. So far i only got the deletion issue fixed and dont know how to recreate them for the next day. If you got any tips for this, i would be glad

In your situation, can you provide the details of the schedule for executing your function NewsletterHTML by the time-driven trigger?


You can try:

function setDailyTrigger() {
  // Delete any existing daily trigger
  deleteDailyTrigger();
  
  // Set a new daily trigger to run at midnight
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('resetPeriodicTriggers')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(0)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}

function deleteDailyTrigger() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == 'resetPeriodicTriggers') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function resetPeriodicTriggers() {
  // Delete any existing periodic triggers
  deleteExistingPeriodicTriggers();
  // Set new periodic triggers
  setPeriodicTriggers();
}

function deleteExistingPeriodicTriggers() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == 'NewsletterHTML') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function setPeriodicTriggers() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(7); // Set the preferable start time
  startTime.setMinutes(45);
  startTime.setSeconds(0);

  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(23); // Set the preferable end time
  endTime.setMinutes(45);
  endTime.setSeconds(0);

  var intervalMinutes = 120; // Set the interval in minutes

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var nextRunTime = new Date();
  nextRunTime.setTime(Math.ceil(currentTime.getTime() / (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000)) * (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));

  if (nextRunTime < startTime) {
    nextRunTime = startTime;
  }

  while (nextRunTime <= endTime) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('NewsletterHTML')
      .timeBased()
      .at(nextRunTime)
      .create();

    nextRunTime.setTime(nextRunTime.getTime() + (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));
  }
}

function NewsletterHTML() {
  // Your NewsletterHTML function logic here
}


How to Use:


Run the setDailyTrigger function manually to set up the initial
daily trigger.
The daily trigger will run resetPeriodicTriggers every day at
midnight, ensuring your periodic triggers are recreated fresh each
day.


Thanks, i will try that one out and let you know!

Everything went fine btw! Thanks a lot
